# Where to find audio recordings for a 'learn to spell' program?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, voice, spelling

Where can I find or buy, in bulk, recordings of 20,000+ English words, read by native speakers? (preferably available as individual audio files with an index)

I don't want to use a "text to speech" program if possible because the quality isn't good enough for people who are trying to learn a language.

Comment: maybe you can take a look here http://arael.shtooka.net/swf/english/

Comment: That is exceptionally good. Do you know of a British English version, as this is my main market?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Linguistic Data Consortium](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/) sells these kinds of data. Check out the [American English Spoken Lexicon](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/CatalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC99L23), for example.

Comment: That site also looks great. Like I said to *blizpasta*, is there an equivalent for British (UK) English?

Comment: I can't find such a corpus now, but please browse through their catalog (at /Catalog) or send them an email. If they don't have it, they might know where to find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let people know what I did in the end:

---

I found [Shtooka](http://shtooka.net/soft/shtooka_recorder/en/), which is a free program for recording lists of words easily and automatically.